# Is there a camera that records video with a quality and style similar to the Black Magic Pocket 4k?

Tags: video-quality, canon, 4k, blackmagic, sony

I was looking for a camera to record videos. My aim is to record videos to make films and music videos. I know there are many factors that are independent of the camera to make videos with a 'cinematographic' look, but I was looking for a camera that would be close to recording like this: [Démira - Dragons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKLui8nDMaY), though my budget is up to around 1,100-1,200 dollars.

It is very important for me to find a camera that works good in low light conditions and with a good slow motion.

I was considering a Canon camera, but recently I was recommended to buy a Black Magic camera. Someone mentioned to me the Black Magic Pocket 4k camera and I looked some footage uploaded to YouTube. I absolutely loved the style of the video. It looked very cinematographic and I found several videos comparing it to professional 'Hollywood' cameras, and it could record with a similar quality.

The problem is that this camera is a little bit beyond my budget (it costs around 1400 dollars), and there is no physical shop where I can actually see the product. The only way I have to buy it is by Internet, so I fear that the camera may arrive damaged or maybe I will be scammed.

I would prefer to buy a camera from a more known brand like Canon, Sony or maybe Panasonic.

So is it any other camera by Canon or Sony or any other manufacturer that records with a similar style and quality to the Black Magic Pocket 4k?

Comment: If your concern is that Blackmagic isn't an established brand, they have an established record of great products that shouldn't be too hard to research. They create top of the line products and they're the company behind DaVinci Resolve - the best color utility out there. I'd strongly recommend finding a camera rental shop near you if possible and renting it - or trying it out in-store if possible.

Comment: This post is  a little off topic, product recommendations are outside the scope of this site. That said, Blackmagic are a very well known maker of professional video cameras and post production equipment. The Pocket Cameras are their entry-level cameras. They don't really do consumer products like Canon, Sony etc. so that's probably why you've never heard of them.